# Componentjs vs requirejs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, components

What benefits to use componentjs (https://github.com/component/component) instead of requirejs?

Both project has the same idea, hard to make choice between them.

Comment: I wouldn't generally consider those two project to be competitors, as they operate at a different level of abstraction. The table at the bottom of this article may be helpful: http://dailyjs.com/2013/01/28/components/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**RequireJS** is *just* a JavaScript file and module loader.

**Component** is a whole system which allows you to package HTML+JS+CSS+Images+Fonts in a one module, component. Component also provides package registry(*vs npm*), dependency handling(*vs requirejs*), build and task system(*vs grunt/gulp*).

There's good document where component is compared to other build/package handling tools:
https://github.com/component/guide/blob/master/component/vs.md

This blog post helped me to understand component: http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/55280740882/using-component-js